# Entity Framework database update returning "cannot find object error"

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a class `User` in a class library as follows:

Superclass called `Base`:

```
namespace Shared_class_library.Models;

public abstract class Base
{
    public Base()
    {
        LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
        CreatedDate = CreatedDate ?? LastUpdated;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then a class called `User` which inherits from `Base`:

```
namespace Shared_class_library.Models;

public class User : Base
{
    private User()
    {
    }

    public User(string name, string email)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<DietaryRequirement>? DietaryRequirements { get; set; }
    public Squad? Squad { get; set; }
    public List<ReferenceChampion>? ChampionRoles { get; set; }
}
```

I have a class called `ReferenceChampions`:

```
namespace Shared_class_library.Models
{
    public class ReferenceChampion : Base
    {
        public ReferenceChampion()
        {
        }

        public ReferenceChampion(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<User> users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want there to be a many to many relationship between `User` and `Champion`, i.e a user can be many different type of champion, and each type of champion can have many different users.

I define this in my `DbContext` like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(u => u.ChampionRoles)
    .WithMany(u => u.users);
```

The problem I am having is when I run the migration command

```
dotnet ef migrations add firstmigration
```

and then

```
dotnet ef database update
```

I get this error:

> Cannot find the object "DietaryRequirements" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

The class in question `DietaryRequirements` is:

```
namespace Shared_class_library.Models;

public class DietaryRequirement : Base
{
    private DietaryRequirement()
    {
    }

    public DietaryRequirement(string requirement)
    {
        Requirement = requirement;
    }

    public string Requirement { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not sure why this error is coming up as there isn't any relationship here between `ReferenceChampion` and `DietaryRequirement`.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Why do you think it has anything to do with ReferenceChampion?  It’s referenced by User

Comment: Truth be told I dont have huge amounts of experience with EF so didn't understand what was causing the issue, do you think its coming from User?

Comment: It’s referenced in User so EF wants to map it.  Try configuring it and see if that removes the error

Comment: Configure it how? Sorry I'm confused what you mean

Comment: Same way you configured the user to Champions reference.  Or add a DbSet<DoetaryRequirement> property to your DbContext; EF just needs to know to include it in the model somehow

Comment: Do you see the dietary requirements table in your database? Would you post this latest migration file?

Comment: Sure @JohnGlenn its posted here as its quite long: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OoltKl

Comment: @Yohan I see that it created two tables for DietaryRequirement - one prefixed with Reference. Is that expected?

Comment: Yes that should be happening based on the models